# Django - JQuery AJAX : How to filter "POST"-ed json on "GET"?

Tags: jquery, python, json, ajax, django

When passing a JSON to Django views, it's supposed to be using `POST`. Using GET will append a long URL that would throw a long URI error.

I am trying to implement a filter on objects in JSON type of functionality using ajax. I have two filter options, by text and by dropdown, where the users can filter one or the other or both.

To do this I pass these two data using `GET`.

So essentially its:

- `JSON` : `POST`
- `filter1` & `filter2` : `GET`

The main problem is, where I can't keep the `POST`-ed json (ofcourse, since its `POST`) but its also unconventional to make a global variable in Python (not like in Java) so I can't keep it until GET gets called so the filters passed can use it on those objects (not directly from the models).

Thank you so much in advance for giving suggestions!

Comment: If you need to store data between requests, you should use the session.

Comment: @DanielRoseman ah! let me read that. I've only been using HttpResponse, render and redirect in python so far

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you for suggesting I read it! Fixed my problem! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django Maintain Session in a very good way you can use Django Session Variables there Or u Can Pass the filter data in Post along with your data